# How can , really, there be elements greater than the limit superior in a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

This is quoted from wikipedia,

> The limit superior of $x_n$ is the smallest real number
>   $b$ such that, for any positive real number $\epsilon$ , there
>   exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_n < b + \epsilon$ for
>   all n > N . In other words, any number larger than
>   the limit superior is an eventual upper bound for the
>   sequence. Only a **finite number of elements of the
>   sequence are greater** than $b + \epsilon$ .

Now doesn't all the elements lie within $b$ i.e. $\forall x \in <x_n> , x \leq b $ ? Isn't the limit superior the upper bound of the sequence? If so, why should there be any elements greater than $b$ as said in the bolded statement of wikipedia above? How can there be elements, though finite, greater than $b$? Where am I mistaking? Please help as I am new in this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the sequence $88, 1/2, 3/4,7/8,15/16,\dots$. The limsup is $1$.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Hi, sir. Yes the element of the sequence like $15/16$ is greater than the limsup. So, basically what does limsup actually tell? I thought it as the upper bound. Was I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. It is the largest **limit point**.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Sir, [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-take-it-limit) , the limsup is associated with the limit of the sequence of the least upper bounds of the main sequence. How can there be more than one lub for a sequence?

Comment: There is only one lub (sup). The limsup is sometimes equal to the sup, but often different and smaller.

Comment: @André Nicolas: So, basically the site is talking of accumulation points, right? BTW, accumulation points are those where elements of the sequence are concentrated & only a few of the elements are located beyond the accumulation points, right?

Comment: Yes, you have the idea, you can think of it as the sup of the accumulation points.

Answer (score 2):

The LIMIT superior is the key. Note, $\limsup s_n=\limsup s_{n+k}$ for all $k$. Be careful with your definition. If it was just the "sup" of the sequence, then you would be correct. But it is the LIM sup.

The definition of lim sup is $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sup \{ s_k\colon k>n\} $. So if $\limsup s_n =L$, there can be finitely many points$p_1,\cdots,p_l$ greater than $L$, because there is some $n$ such that you only consider the supremum of the set AFTER that.

Edit, just as a tip for analysis. Analysis is the study of infinities. So as a general rule, finitely many things don't matter.

Comment: Thanks sir for posting the answer. Can you tell me what is the difference between sup & limsup & least upper bound of a sequence? I'll be grateful to you:)

Comment: Sir, can you tell what you meant by $\lim{\sup}s_n = \lim{\sup}s_{n+k}$?

Comment: I just gave the definition of limsup. You already know what sup (which is a synonym for least upper bound) means.

Comment: Yes sir, but if sup is synonymous to least upper bound, then limsup actually does implies there must be a convergent sequence of sup whose limit is limsup, right? So, is there actually a sequence of upper bounds? After reading [this](https://plus.maths.org/content/maths-minute-take-it-limit) , I think there exits such sequence but they are actually accumulation points...

Comment: ...But do you think this is right ie. the sup points are actually accumulation points? And the limit of the sequence of those accumulation points is the limsup?

Answer (score 0):

The limit superior is  the limit of the sequence derived from $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ by starting further and further; explicitly, it is the sequence:
$$b_0=\sup_{n\ge 0}a_n,\enspace b_1=\sup_{n\ge 1}a_n,\enspace b_2=\sup_{n\ge 2}a_n,\dots$$ 
which is a decreasing sequence.